How to configure nuxt 3 to name components in dev tools according to their filepath?
In our nuxt 3 project, we have a project structure like this:
components/
   MyButton/
      index.vue
      index.scss
      index.composable.vue

For the most part this works as expected, where "MyButton" can be used as a component anywhere in the project. The issue comes when trying to use any kind of DevTools. Here the entire component tree will look something like:
Index
   Index
   Index
      NuxtLink
   Index

Needless to say, this makes debugging with DevTools very difficult.
A solution that works, but I'd rather avoid as it adds unnecessary bloat, is to put this script tag at the end of each SFC:
<script lang="ts">
export default {
  name: 'MyButton',
};
</script>

I'd rather just configure nuxt itself in a way that it will use the full relative path of the component for the DevTools, the same way as it does for referencing the component in the .vue files. So far I could find no such setting. I tried using a plugin, but while I could confirm the name is set correctly in the console output, this does not seem to affect the name in the DevTools at all.
plugins/fix-names.ts
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.mixin({
    beforeCreate() {
      if (!import.meta.dev) return;
      const filePath = this.$options.__file as string; // Get the file path of the component
      if (!filePath) return;

      // Only take the file path after components/
      const namePath = filePath.split('components/')[1]?.replace('.vue', '') || '';
      if (!namePath) return;

      const directories = namePath.split('/');
      const dirName = directories
        .map((dir) => `${dir.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${dir.slice(1)}`)
        .join('');

      this.$options.name = dirName;
      this.$options.__name = dirName;
      console.log('Component name:', this.$options.name);
    },
  });
});

